# Higher Order Expansion For Median of Random Variable

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable and let $M(X)$ be its median. Using Jensen's inequality, one can prove that

$$|M(X) - \mathbb{E}[X]| \le \sigma $$
which implies that $M(X) = \mathbb{E}[X] + O(\operatorname{Var}(X)^{1/2})$ provided that $Var(X)$ exists. My questions are:

- Can we get a 'higher order' asymptotic expansion for the median in terms of further moments of $X$ ?
- Can we sharpen the above inequality if we assume certain tail behaviors of $X$ such as the tail dies exponentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no asymptotic expansions for the median in terms of higher moments.

Consider two variables which have all the same moments, like the lognormal variable with pdf
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(\frac{-(\log x)^2}{2}\right)$$
and its [perturbation](https://mathoverflow.net/a/3553/44143) with pdf
$$g(x) = f(x)(1 + \sin(2\pi \log x)).$$
Each has $E[X^n]=\exp(n^2/2)$, and they decay at similar rates, but the lognormal variable has median $1$ and its perturbation has median $1.128$.

Comment: Ah I see, this is a great example and perfectly answers my question